# How to debug Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm facing quite a number of logical errors which I'm unaware of. Like a normal programmer, the thing to solve your errors is by debugging it first. May I know how to debug it? Because when i tried doing so, it already shows me an error:

"Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant Object::ApplicationController"

May I know how to solve this error and how to debug? Thanks! :)

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529462/debugging-in-rails) for more detailed answer.

Comment: a full guide can be found here http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either do it the quick and dirty way, in your code:

```
raise my_object.inspect
```

This will throw an exception with the information about the object.

Or use the [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html) gem.

I recommend you read the [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) chapter in the Rails documentation.