# Debugging in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you debug 'relatively' successfully in RubyonRails? I am aware and use extensively, the followings:

- Terminal
- Rails console
- Developer Tools
- Log Files (Production/Develpoment)

It would help to debug lot faster, if there are other techniques available independent to environment it is running on.

Comment: try this `<%= debug (@object)%>` in your view

Comment: I personally use pry https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: log files, raise helper,logger.debug()..etc

Comment: pry + pry debugger is probably what's mostly similar to "debugger"

Comment: you might want to have a look at this blog post http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These gems make debugging a Rails app a lot easier, without using a *real* debugger:

```
group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "pry-rails"
end
```

[Better errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gives you a full stack trace with REPL in your browser when you trip over an error.

With [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) you can put a `binding.pry` statement somewhere in your code and the next request will be halted at that line. Now you can inspect the running code in your console, inspect or change variables and type `exit` to resume the request.

Both gems have a lot in common, for me the main difference is that better_errors gives nice feedback and a REPL on unforeseen errors, while pry gives me the possibility to halt, inspect and resume a request when I want to.